# What is replaced absolutely-positioned boxes in css?

Tags: css, flexbox

### Background

I'm making Flex component in React.

```js
const Flex: React.FC<FlexBoxProps> = ({
  children,
  fluid = false,
  alignItems = 'normal',
  justifyContent = 'normal',
  flexDirection = 'row',
  flexWrap = 'nowrap',
  rowGap = '0',
  columnGap = '0',
  ...
}) => {
```

### Problem

I found that default value of alignItems is `normal` in [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items#formal_definition).

But, I can't understand the explanation of `normal` property.
For example,

```
In absolutely-positioned layouts,   
the keyword behaves like start on replaced absolutely-positioned boxes,   
and as stretch on all other absolutely-positioned boxes.
```

What is the `replaced absolutely-positioned boxes` in this context ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A **replaced element** is an element whose content is outside the scope of the document's CSS.

So, for example, an `iframe`, `img` or `video` element which, being "imported" into your document, is not affected by the document's CSS.

A **non-replaced element** is an intrinsic part of the document and recognizes the document's CSS.

Hence, an **absolutely-positioned replaced element** is an absolutely-positioned `img`, `canvas`, `video` or `iframe`. Being a replaced element, it won't recognize the document's styles. On these elements, `normal` behaves like `start`.

On other **absolutely-positioned elements** (non-replaced), `normal` behaves like `stretch`.

More details in the specs:

- https://drafts.csswg.org/css-display/#replaced-element
- https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/rendering.html#replaced-elements

Answer (score 2):

Replaced elements are elements like `<img>` where the contents of the rendered box aren't affected by CSS. Absolutely positioned boxes are those with a computed value for the position property is `absolute`.

`replaced absolutely-positioned boxes` are boxes which meet both those conditions.